# getelementbyid is not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to write a simple program which retrieves location of the user with help of google maps and assign the formatted address to text box. But it is not working.
here is my code:

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="getelementbyidproblemi.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=MyKEY"></script>



</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div class="row">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Site"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div id="harita" style="width: 900px; height: 400px">
        </div>


        <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.016869, 29.138922);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("harita"), myOptions);
                function displayLocation(latitude, longitude) {
                    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var method = 'GET';
                    var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude + ',' + longitude;
                    var async = true;
                    request.open(method, url, async);
                    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                            var address = data.results[0];
                            console.log(address.formatted_address);
                            console.log(latitude);
                            document.getElementById('Site').innerHTML = address.formatted_address;
                        }
                    };
                    request.send();
                };
                var successCallback = function (position) {
                    var x = position.coords.latitude;
                    var y = position.coords.longitude;
                    displayLocation(x, y);
                };
                var errorCallback = function (error) {
                    var errorMessage = 'Unknown error';
                    switch (error.code) {
                        case 1:
                            errorMessage = 'Permission denied';
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            errorMessage = 'Position unavailable';
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            errorMessage = 'Timeout';
                            break;
                    }
                };
                var options = {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true,
                    timeout: 5000,
                    maximumAge: 0
                };
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, options);
            });
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your last edit fixed the flaw pointed out by @PrashanthReddy - is the original issue still present in your code?

Comment: Can you describe *how* it doesn't work?

Comment: i corrected it, it was a trial when i copied it which resulted in an error, sorry for that.

Comment: text box is empty. As you can see console log is working.

Comment: Amy, no it is not solved. textbox is still empty.

Comment: @FatihSönmez I think you need to show us rendered html. Now your question shows server-template

Comment: @FatihSönmez, try using `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Comment: @MysterX the only file that i have is Default.aspx. I have installed bottstrap and jquery and jquery-ui via nuget. that's all.

Comment: @doutriforce THANX. That worked. But i still wonder why innerHTML doesn't work?

Comment: `innerHtml` applies to every object that can contain HTML (divs, spans, but many other. `value` applies only to objects that have the value attribute (normally, form controls) and `asp:TextBox` is rendered as `<input type="text" />`

Comment: Because form inputs have a value property and non-form elements don't. innerHTML is for changing the HTML/text content of regular elements like divs, spans, paragraphs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the controls `ClientId`.  Webforms renders the control using a complex naming scheme.  Right click on the element and click "Inspect Element" to view the *actual* ID as rendered by Webforms.

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById("Site")
```

Use:

```
document.getElementById('<%= Site.ClientID %>')
```

Comment: That's .net rendering. Did she say she's using .net?

Comment: She's obviously using webforms.  Did you look at the code in the question?

Comment: Didn't even see that textbox...this might be the problem indeed.

Comment: @Amy This worked too. Thank you. Since i have very few reputation, i can not vote your answer as a correct answer.

Comment: I didn't think accepting an answer required rep.  Strange.  An upvote would be nice, if the answer can't be accepted for some reason.

Comment: @Amy i have only 1 rep. i can not upvote either. Sorry for that. But your answer is THE ANSWER. Thanks again. :)